# while loop does not fully respect multi conditions C++

Tags: c++, while-loop

I wanted to make an C++ program that will make calculation of multi result with few info. But that does not even matter that much. Because I have problem with while loop.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
       float c=0.08734,s,t,p,d,g,o,k;
       int z,i;

       d=0;
       p=0;
       o=0;
       cout << "z?" << endl;
       cin >> z;
       cout << "s?" << endl;
       cin >> s;
       cout << "o?" << endl;
       cin >> o;
       g=1*10/(z*s*c);
       cout << g << endl << endl;
       k=o;
       while (d < 810 || p < 42 || o < 40)
       {
        cout << o << endl;
        d=(s*z*o)/c;
        p=(d*c)/(z*s)+2.5;
        o=o+k;
        cout << d << o << p << endl << endl;

        //if ( d>=810 || p >= 42 || o >= 39.5) break;
       }
       cout << d << o << p << endl << endl;

       return 0;
       }
```

I put some additional couts because I tried to debug and fix it. But I could not.
Excatly problem is because while loop stop, AFTER few times that it should. So it override conditions I made in while ( ... ) I tried also with ANDs but same thing happen.
I also tried putting IF inside of while, but that just does not help enough.

example input:
z 2
s 0.852
o 6

output should be:
585.299 36 32.5

Program print:
819.418 48 44.5

NOTE: I am not so interested in making this program to fully work. I want to know where did I made mistake about while loop. I tried this same program in few other programming languages and same thing happen.

Comment: How can your program output that d is 585.299 if d must be bigger then 810 to stop the loop?  Your real output is in line with the code: the loop finishes when the 3 values are bigger than the checked values.

Comment: Parentheses are your friends.

Comment: `A || B || C` is true when at least one of the conditions is true. The negation, `!(A || B || C)`, is `!A && !B && !C`. (And the negation of `o < 40` is not `o >= 39.5`.)

Comment: why do you think the output should be: 585.299 36 32.5 ? the actual output you get respects the condition of your while loop.

Comment: @stefaanv
I need all those 3 value lower than values I set in while.
Thanks you so much for your comment, now I finally understand how while work and why did I not made this program to work.

erip
thanks I will try that.

molbdnilo
unfortunately I need to set float on o comparation. There would be cases where o is 39.6 so 0 < 40 will not do what I need.

shrike
It have to be like that, but I did not know how while excatly work, that why you think it is wrong output.
Value in while is MAX values.

Answer (score 0):

Change the position of conditions in while loop in ascending order like ( o <40  && p < 42 && d <820) and use & operation to get right answer because in your code answer is only dependent to d.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.

First problem was with comparation in while. I used OR (||) but I should use logical and (&&). That is why I though my loop override condition multiply times.

Now only problem is to fix, substracting after while check the values.